# Git commit two project code as single project in the repository

Tags: git, github

I am new on git open source.

Actually I have one android project i.e `AllScan`, SO I commit all the code in original master repository when I made the changes into the code. 
Now I have implemented new functionality in my project to scan the barcodes. SO for that I am using the ZXing (Zebra Crossing) google barcode scanner project or we can say it as library.
Actally ZXing is google project, we have to download it and make it as library, import it with our project in IDE (eclips) and used in our main project as library so it can scan the barcode.

Now I have two projects one is my original `AllScan` and another is google barcode scanner ZXing. But when I try to commit the code that i have made, then how can I commit the both project code so that after taking the clone we can able to run this project perfectly. Means I can able to clone the two project code. SO how can I commit the that two project code.

Comment: have you found the solution, the same situation is with me but at bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not making changes to the zxing code, what you may want to do is add zxing as a **dependency**.

It looks like Android likes gradle for this task. See [this doc](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#dependencies) for more information on managing dependenices with gradle:

> When some of your dependencies are available in a remote repository, you do not have to download them and copy them into your project. The Android Studio build system supports remote Maven dependencies. Maven is a popular software project management tool that helps organize project dependencies using repositories.
>
> Many popular software libraries and tools are available in public Maven repositories. For these dependencies you only have to specify their Maven coordinates, which uniquely identify each element in a remote repository.

They recommend including from the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/). On that site you will find [com.google.zxing:android-integration](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.zxing%7Candroid-core%7C3.1.0%7Cjar)  which you can add to gradle with:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
```

This will enable you to import the code during your build rather than worrying about keeping the zxing code in your repository.

If you really do want to embed the zxing code in your git repo you should look into [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). There is [a tutorial here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial) for more information.